# How to output rEFind boot interface to external monitor

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, multi-boot, refind

I connected my AOC monitor through HDMI to my HP laptop. And I am using rEFind as a boot manager to choose between Arch Linux and Windows 10. But the rEfind is shown only on my laptop monitor.

I understand that at this moment of booting there are not drivers loaded for the monitor, because this is happening during the OS boot process. But I know, that for GRUB for example there is a way to set the output through some options in it's config file.

So is there any way to make rEFind show it's interface on external connected monitor?

Also people say that there is an option in a BIOS to boot into specified monitor (external/LCD). But unfortunately there is no such option in my BIOS version.

Comment: Roderick specifically mentions video card drivers: https://rodsbooks.com/refind/drivers.html.  I would have a look.

Comment: сразу видно аппер интермидиат